# installing nomayaBundle error

Tags: symfony, bundle

Hey guys i am trying to add the bundle NomayaSocialBundle, and i am getting this error

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
The child node "buttons" at path "nomaya_social" must be configured.

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache 
handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]
An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command:
    [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
The child node "buttons" at path "nomaya_social" must be configured.
```

I don t really know how to fix it so this is what i got after executing the command php composer.phar update nomaya/social-bundle

```
    C:\wamp\www\MTOCrowdRise>php -r "eval('>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
enter code here`All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Composer successfully installed to: C:\wamp\www\MTOCrowdRise\composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
C:\wamp\www\MTOCrowdRise>php composer.phar update nomaya/social-bundle
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. 
This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Generating autoload files
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
The child node "buttons" at path "nomaya_social" must be configured.

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache 
handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]
An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command:
    [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
The child node "buttons" at path "nomaya_social" must be configured.

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] 
[--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] 
[--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
 [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] 
[--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: Did you add already some configuration connected to bundle to config.yml?

Comment: @PawełMikołajczuk yes i did

Comment: can you check my answer and show us your config for bundle from config.yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably added already bundle class to AppKernel, and this bundle require configuration from app config.

Just add missing configuration to config.yml (minimal one):

```
nomaya_social:
    buttons:
        facebook:
            url:            null
            locale:         "fr_FR"
            send:           false
            width:          300
            showFaces:      false
            layout:         "button_count"
    links: 
        facebook:           "http://www.facebook.com/yann.chauvel"
        googleplus:         "https://plus.google.com/105931415830389032796"
```

And call manually `php app/console cache:clear` - it should clear cache without issues.